# Disable 'Previous' button on 1st slide? Nivoslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I'm using [Nivoslider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/) for a web project I am working on.

As you can see from the above link, the "prev" button displays even when on the 1st slide.

Is it possible I can make NivoSlider "linear" and **only display the previous button if the slide number is greater than 0**?

It seems NivoSlider is set up as 'infinite' or 'circular' by default, but I'm sure there must be a way to alter this.

Many thanks for any help with this :-)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would stick to Nivoslider if it doesn't fit your needs? There are literally thousands of excellent jQuery slider plugins out there that will probably do exactly what you want. 

For example; [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) is pretty lightweight and powerful.

Comment: That's a great point - I think I'll try jCarouselLite and see how I fair - thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom afterChange function when you initialize the slider.

```
var sliderSelector = '#slider'; // Replace with your slider selector
$(sliderSelector).nivoSlider({
    // .. Other config here
    controlNav: true, // This solution relies on this to work
    afterChange: function() {
        // Hide prev button if on first slide
        if ($(sliderSelector + ' .nivo-controlNav .nivo-control:first').hasClass('active'))
            $(sliderSelector + ' .nivo-prevNav').hide();
        else
            $(sliderSelector + ' .nivo-prevNav').show();

        // Hide next button if on last slide
        if ($(sliderSelector + ' .nivo-controlNav .nivo-control:last').hasClass('active'))
            $(sliderSelector + ' .nivo-nextNav').hide();
        else
            $(sliderSelector + ' .nivo-nextNav').show();
    },
    afterLoad: function() {
        // If you have randomStart set to true, then you might check with what slide it started and act accordingly.
        // If you use the default, then this should be all you need
        $(sliderSelector + ' .nivo-prevNav').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Many, many thanks for your answer - apologies for my delay. I will try this shortly and let you know how I get on. Thanks again.